# Replace numbers to text from two mySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

i was searching and didn't find anything similar to this

I have a two mySQL tables
table1 contains few rows and in a both of those tables there are 8 unique numbers
in table 2 there are again 8 unique numbers which also contains text explaining what those numbers are.

for demonstration
table1 contains ID in which is "12345678"
table2 contains same number "12345678" and in next row of table2 description defines those number like "this is my name"

How can I replace results with PHP to change those numbers from table1 to description in table2?

Comment: you want to show to the users only the description of table 2 that has same number as table1

Comment: yes thats what i want to display

Answer (score 0):

How do these numbers increment?

You could select the numbers out of your first table, store them in a variable, loop them through a foreach function $key->$value that checks each number and accordingly set's a string to each. Then set a sql that inserts $key[0] through $key[7] into table #2, you want to order by ID. Pro Tip: If your numbers increment according to a certain rule, you could define $key as your first number (12345678) outside of the function, and then increment it in your function each time i increments. I'm sorry if that sounds too complicated, I think it would work. There is a better way to insert them into table #2, but that was the quickest idea I came up with. It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question the right way. U need to inner join those two tables and return the description from table 2 then display the data. Use the code below for that task:

```
<?php
define('host', 'localhost');
define('database', 'dbname');
define('username', 'root');
define('pass', '');
$conn = mysqli_connect(host, username, pass, database);

if(!$conn){

    die('Connection with the db failed: '. mysqli_error($conn));
}

$query = "SELECT Table2.Description 
          FROM Table2 
          INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID=Table2.ID";

$update_data= mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if(!$update_data){

    die("Error: ".mysqli_error($conn));
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($update_data)){

    echo $row['Description'];
}

?>
```